# Does jQuery remove also destroy resizables/draggables?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-resizable

In jQuery + jQuery UI, does calling `.remove()` on an element that also has resizable/draggable configured on it inherently call `.resizable('destroy')` + `.draggable('destroy')`, or an equivalent method that properly cleans everything up?  Do I have to destroy the resizable/draggables before calling remove?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you don't need to call `destroy` function before calling `remove`. **jQuery `.remove` triggers `.destroy` inherently**. I could not find this documented anywhere and I was surprised to find this out.

When including `jQuery UI`, the library overrides jQuery's `cleanData` function to include the code to trigger `.remove` event. (https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js#L16)

Check this demo - http://jsfiddle.net/UMYzD - the `.remove` handler is called when calling `.remove` function. Now uncheck the jQuery UI from the left pane (http://jsfiddle.net/UMYzD/1) and you would see that the `.remove` event handler is not triggered any more when calling `.remove`.

```
$.cleanData = function( elems ) {
    for ( var i = 0, elem; (elem = elems[i]) != null; i++ ) {
      try {
        $( elem ).triggerHandler( "remove" );
       // http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8235
      } catch( e ) {}
    }
    _cleanData( elems ); 
};
```

The line `$( elem ).triggerHandler( "remove" );` triggers the `.remove` event bound on that element by the widget and all the way it calls the `.destroy` on the widget inherently.

Below is the call hierarchy,

[image]

Below is the snapshot from fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nxrzY/1/

[image]

Comment: `I could not find this documented anywhere and I was surprised to find this out.` While is not written "remove calls destroy" in docs (and as you showed in the stacks), it's written `In addition to the elements themselves, all bound events and jQuery data associated with the elements are removed`. But anyways, thanks for showing the stack.

Comment: @RaphaelDDL No, the docs specifically talks about the element. This is not about removing the element or its event.. it triggers a specific event "remove" to internally call the widgets destroy function.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from jQuery's [remove() docs](http://api.jquery.com/remove/):

> Similar to `.empty()`, the `.remove()` method takes elements out of the DOM. Use `.remove()` when you want to remove the element itself, as well as everything inside it. **In addition to the elements themselves, all bound events and jQuery data associated with the elements are removed.** To remove the elements without removing data and events, use `.detach()` instead.

So supposedly, it would remove the resizable and draggable events as well. Probably jQuery might call `unbind()` or `off()` prior to removing from DOM.